# How to select if has not an element

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I would like that if the user clicks in a `<td>` of a  `<tr>`  that **DOESN'T** have an input element of type **checkbox**, it will call a function.

Actually, I'm trying to do in this way:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#mytable tr:has(td)", function (e) {
     //Some code
 }
```

I tried also adding `tr:has(td):not(checkbox)` but doesn't work either.

And In this way didn't work too:

```
if (e.toElement === "input"){
    return;
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Look how is the table:
[image: Table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the right selectors, `:not` and `:has`, but not quite in the right order. Try this:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#mytable tr td:not(:has(:checkbox))", function(e) {
  console.log('this cell has no checkbox');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Fizz</td>
    <td>Buzz</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

is this what you need?, consider that with this code, it does not matter what structure you have inside the tr, if there is a checkbox somewhere, it will work

```js
$(function(){
  $('td').on('click',function(){
  if( $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').length == 0 ){
     console.log('this td does not have a checkbox')
  }
  })
})
```

```css
table{
width:100%;
}

td{
border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>
         <span>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
         </span>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```